# Change sqlite file size after using SQLiteConnection.Delete(object) command with sqlite-net orm

Tags: c#, orm, sqlite, sqlite-net

I am working with sqlite-net ORM. First, I am using big database, file size was about 120 mb. Than I deleted small part of that database But file size is not changed.I am trying use vacuum but I can't use vacuum command. Where I should use vacuum command?

```
public class Entities : SQLiteConnection
{

    public Entities(string dbPath, bool createDatabase = false)
        : base(dbPath)
    {
    }
}
```

My SQLiteConnection is inside the [SQLite.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs) sqlite-net orm.

Comment: There is no "vacuum" in the code you've shown.

Comment: My question was how I could use vacuum command inside the my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick way using sqlite commands using with SQLitePCL library.

```
public async Task<int> Vacuum()
{
     return Db.SqliteConnection.ExecuteAsync("VACUUM;");
}
```